# Styled-components: Style not updated after switching from mobile

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mfnnph?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js):

- Open the app in desktop width, notice the `div` has green background
- Reduce browser width to mobile, the `div` background should change to gray
- Again, increase browser width to desktop, notice the gray background remains, instead of green

What should have happened

- The background in last step should be green as in the first step, isn't it?

Logging value of `isMobile` does seem to show it is being updated.

---

Here is also code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive';

let MenuItem = styled.div`
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color: green;    

  // Select those items which are children of .submenu
  .submenu & {
    background-color: ${({ isMobile }) => {
      return isMobile && 'lightgray';
    }};
  }           
`;

function App() {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 524px)' });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="submenu">
        <MenuItem isMobile={isMobile}>test</MenuItem>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import {useMediaQuery} from 'react-responsive';
    
    let MenuItem = styled.div`
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border:1px solid red;
      background-color: green;
    `;
    
    function App() {
        const isMobile = useMediaQuery({query: '(max-width: 524px)'});
        const [color, setColor] = useState('green');
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (isMobile) setColor('silver');
            else setColor('green');
        }, [isMobile])
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="submenu">
                    <MenuItem style={{background: color}} isMobile={isMobile}>test</MenuItem>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

export default App;
```

Comment: this didn't answer my question, why bg is gray

Comment: React elements are immutable. Once you create an element, you can’t change its children or attributes. An element is like a single frame in a movie: it represents the UI at a certain point in time.

With our knowledge so far, the only way to update the UI is to create a new element, and pass it to root.render()

to render a react component you need to create your own state and change it

Comment: That's not it, I am not mutating, I am passing new props which is allowed both by react and styled components, check their docs

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct answer:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t7gqwx?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js

You shouldn't use `.submenu &`.

Comment: did you try that? doesn't work

Comment: Why I should not use it? **It is documented feature of styled components**. Check their docs

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Because you don't can have access to parents from inside a child. `MenuItem` is a child of `.submenu` and you want to have access to the parent. (versa of that is possible). Is right?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting. It's there.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Yes, you're right. Although in there used in this way because it is necessary to select a special`Thing` (there are multiple `Thing`s) and in your case no need to do that `.submenu &`. (There is one MenuItem). But anyway your code isn't incorrect! I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write this as:

```
const MenuItem = styled.div` 
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border:1px solid red;
      background-color: green;
    `;

const SubMenu = styled.div`
  ${MenuItem} {
    background-color: ${({ isMobile }) => (isMobile ? `red` : 'lightgray')};
  }
  `;

function App() {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 524px)' });
  return (
    <>
      <SubMenu isMobile={isMobile}>
        <MenuItem>MenuItem in SubMenu</MenuItem>
      </SubMenu>
      <MenuItem>MenuItem</MenuItem>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mqxwbd?file=src/App.js)

Comment: My point is not to rewrite, rather understand why it doesn't work in my example; so this answer isn't what I am looking for